# CSS transition not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have a Shopify theme with a search form that uses an animation on its width attribute, to be triggered by a jQuery call:

```
  <span id="store-search">
    <div><a class="iconfont big-search" tabindex="0">&#0035;</a></div>
    <form action="http://penumbra-foundation.myshopify.com/search" method="get" class="search-bar">
      <input id="query" tabindex="0" name="q" type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == value) { this.value = ''; }">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" style="display:none" />
    </form>
  </span>
```

Here's the associated js:

```
<script>
  $('a.big-search').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$('#store-search form:first *:input:first').focus();},0);
  });
</script>
```

This uses the fix from [focus() not working in safari or chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074347/focus-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome) but with no success.

And the CSS for the animation is here:

```
width: 0;
-webkit-transition: width 1000ms linear;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0;
-moz-transition: width 1000ms linear 0;
-o-transition: width 1000ms linear 0;
transition: width 1000ms linear 0;
```

Link is here:

http://penumbra-foundation.myshopify.com/

It's the big outlined magnifying glass search bar against a maroon background. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also the selector Looks good, have you tried `$("#query").focus();`? why did you not just use `placeholder="Search"`?

Comment: Changed to placeholder="Search" and removed the timer, still no response or console errors in Safari

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the width animation isn't happening, not that the focus isn't working.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes that's more precisely the issue.

Comment: But why are you using the timeout in the First Place. Try to wrap your Code like this:  $(function(){ //your js });

Comment: @DuncanMalashock You should provide the animation code then.

Comment: @NicoO refer to the fix I linked to in the original post for the reason I'm using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is an acceptable solution for you (it is certainly not a great/perfect solution), but it looks like it works if you change the starting width of your input element there from `0em` to `0.07em` (or `0.07rem` for consistency with your other units of measure).

I can't find any documentation about it, but it looks like Safari is having trouble starting the transition from 0 (or even small numbers that it considers to close enough to 0).