# OnFocus event does not trigger in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I want to execute a Javascript when user set a focus on the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onfocus="onFocusSubmit()">
```

But on Safari browser, the event never gets called. I have tried `onMouseOver` event, which works perfectly well, and I have tried other browsers like Chrome, which also does not have a problem.

Does anybody know a way around this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074347/focus-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome#2099337

Comment: It is talking about a tab that Safari and Chrome does not recognize. I am talking about a button that Safari does not recognize while Chrome does.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a workaround as following.
I set a keydown event on the previous object (which is not a button)

```
document.querySelector('#password').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key != "Tab" && e.key != "Enter") return;
    //Execute();
});
```

Also I put a same function when it gets mousemove on the button.

```
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#submit').focus();
    //Execute();
});
```